# Error ajax can not pass params to Spring Controller

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-mvc

```
var companyCode = [];

var data = {
        'companyCode': companyCode, //array this may be problem
        'actionUserGroup': usersession.userGroup,
        'formType': 'IN',
        'actionId': usersession.userId,
        'submittedDate': [submitted_s,submitted_e] //array this may be problem
};
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data :  JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    url: appConfig.endPoint + 'search/myTask', 
    success: function(data){

    console.log(data);
    }
});
```

{this ajax side}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JSONObject searchmyTask(Model model, HttpSession session,
        @RequestParam (value="companyCode") String[] companyCode,
        @RequestParam (value="actionUserGroup") String actionUserGroup,
        @RequestParam (value="formType") String formType,
        @RequestParam (value="actionId") String actionId,
        @RequestParam (value="submittedDate") String[] submittedDates
        ) throws Exception {

    /**
     * if "userGroup" = 'ADMIN'
```

{this Spring Controller}

http://localhost:9091/gcbg/search/myTask 400 (Required String[] parameter 'companyCode' is not present)  jquery.min.js:2 POST

{this one is error}

Please help me to figure out this problem. Thanks

Comment: Don't use images for code please

Comment: ok, I will edit

Comment: I have edited already , Please help me.

Comment: @KullanitNanongkhai did you try the response i give you?

Comment: @cralfaro I have tried that solution already but it return this one "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Required String[] parameter 'companyCode[]' is not present)" , Can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

i just did few changes to make it work, so if you modify the next options should work for yourself.

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    data :  data,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    url: appConfig.endPoint + 'search/myTask', 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JSONObject searchmyTask(Model model, HttpSession session,
    @RequestParam (value="companyCode[]") String[] companyCode,
    @RequestParam (value="actionUserGroup") String actionUserGroup,
    @RequestParam (value="formType") String formType,
    @RequestParam (value="actionId") String actionId,
    @RequestParam (value="submittedDate[]") String[] submittedDates
    ) throws Exception {
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it still has an error ""Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Required String[] parameter 'companyCode[]' is not present)"", why the params as array did not come to method.

Comment: did you change the controller parameters names?